# How to make ip Address static (eth0)

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I'm having a really hard time configuring ubuntu 13.04 to have a static ip address. I have tried multiple solutions but everytime I reboot (can't do the network reset command because ubuntu freezes) I end up with no connection.

Here is what I get when i type ifconfig into the terminal:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:bc:07:cb  
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::12bf:48ff:febc:7cb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1763067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1024326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2284491220 (2.2 GB)  TX bytes:136809317 (136.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:185688 (185.6 KB)  TX bytes:185688 (185.6 KB)
```

I have also tried this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.160
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 24.222.0.94
        dns-nameservers 24.222.0.95
```

If anyone could help me it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which IP are you trying to get static?  And are you using NetworkManager at all?

Comment: @Qasim - Removing networkmanager is not a solution.  I prefer wicd myself, but it's still not a solution.  It could break loads of things to just rip it out.  It's a lot like saying, just remove dnsmasq if you want old style DNS management.  It could work, but it's not fixing the problem.

Comment: hmmmmm got it.. comment removed about network-manager

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps to make the IP address of a system static:

1. Open interface file (`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`)
2. Look for

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```
3. Replace the above commands with

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.100(Enter desired ip here)
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.1.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   ```
4. Then enter

   ```
   sudo ifdown eth0; sudo ifup eth0
   ```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP shows?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.160
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 24.222.0.94 24.222.0.95
```